# Confusion matrix for multilabel classification

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab, confusion-matrix

I've trained two multilabel image classifiers. The first labels images in categories `m1, m2`, whereas the second labels them according to categories `t1, t2, t3` for instance. The important part is that the models do not use the same number of labels.

Using python, I now would like to investigate the correlation between predictions, and the first question that come to me is: of all images labelled as `mj` by the first model, `j=1,2`, how many were also labelled as `tk` by the second model, `k=1,2,3`?

That is, suppose my predictions were

```
img1 = ['m1', 'm2', 't1']
img1 = ['m1', 't1']
img1 = ['m1', 'm2', 't1', 't3']
```

I then would like to have a correlation of counts of each category in a confusion matrix -- I apologise if the terminology I'm using is not correct:

```
   t1 t2 t3
m1 3  0  1
m2 2  0  1
```

I've tried to construct it with either `pandas.crosstab()` or scikit-learn confusion matrix, but I couldn't find a solution.

Moreover, in the actual case I will have to handle 1200 images, and there are 28 labels from the first model and 120 from the second.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

As my question received no answer nor comment, it might not be so relevant. In any case, I've managed to find a solution and I'll share it here just in case.

The example is a bit better than the one I gave in the answer.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

M = []
M.append([1,2,3])
M.append([2,3])
M.append([1,3])
M.append([1,3])

T = []
T.append([1,2,3])
T.append([2,4])
T.append([1,3,4])
T.append([1])

labels1 = [1,2,3]
labels2 = [1,2,3,4]

counts = []
for m in labels1:
    ids = [id_ for id_ in range(4) if m in M[id_]]
    array = np.concatenate([T[id_] for id_ in ids])
    counts.append([np.bincount(array)[t] for t in labels2])

df = pd.DataFrame(counts)
df.columns = labels2
df.index = labels1


ax = sns.heatmap(df)
plt.show()
```

```
counts
>> output: [[3, 1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1, 1], [3, 2, 2, 2]]
```